# PHP preg match / replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to read the string $mysting and replace all incident of e.x.

```
<img src="dummypic.jpg alt="dummy pic">
```

with

```
<img src="dummypic.jpg alt="dummy pic" title="dummy pic">
```

in other words add the title where it is missing, and make the title tag have the same value as the alt tag.

some incident my have additional parameters like border, with, height - and these should be left untouched ...

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/cm8ea5

please post the code of what you have already tried if you need a quicker response from the community.

Comment: Just to note, title and alt are attributes, not tags. And technically image tags don't require a title attribute as the alt attribute is used by screen readers and when images are disabled to show a description of the image, but that's way not the point :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a regex, have a look into [PHP DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to modify attributes, especially if there will be any complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You could use phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) to do that:

```
$qp = qp($html);
foreach ($qp->find("img") as $img) {
    $img->attr("title", $img->attr("alt"));
}
print $qp->writeHTML();
```

Though it might be feasible in this simple case to resort to an regex:

```
preg_replace('#(<img\s[^>]*)(\balt=)("[^"]+")#', '$1$2$3 title=$3', $h);
```

(It would make more sense to use preg_replace_callback to ensure no title= attribute is present yet.)

Answer (score 0):

You really want to do this using an html parser instead of regexes. Regexes are not suited for html processing.

Comment: Please provide an example, not generic advise.

Comment: well the OP did not post his code... i think it's very kind for anyone to be even answering.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a link to a well known answer!

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: That would fit better in a comment

Comment: My answer is a referral to another answer, this fits the criteria for an answer perfectly IMO

Answer (score 0):

I usually write quick dirty hacks in these types of situations (usually working with structured data, that might have inconsistencies such as templating engine tags, conditionals, etc.). IMO its a terrible solution, but I can bang out these scripts super fast.

Eg.

```
<?
$html = '
<img src="dummypic.jpg" alt="dummy pic">
<img src="dummypic2.jpg" alt="dummy pic 2">

blahaahhh

<img src="dummypic.jpg" alt="dummy pic">
<img src="dummypic2.jpg" alt="dummy pic 2">
';

$tags = explode('<img', $html);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($tags); $i++)
{
    $src = explode('src="', $tags[$i]);
    $src = explode('"', $src[1]);
    $src = str_replace('.jpg', '', $src[0]);   

    $tags[$i] = '<img title="' . $src . '"' . $tags[$i];
}

echo implode('', $tags);
```